# Changing the font size of the heading

Tags: fontsize, abstract

I am writing a report (`\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}`) which has an abstract in the beginning. I am using `\usepackage{abstract}` to write it. Then I am using `\begin{abstract} ... \end{abstract}` to put the abstract in the document. The problem is that the heading "Abstract" is at the same font size as the writing under it, only bold. I need to be able to control the size of this heading. Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 7):

If there are no language requirements (via [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel), for example), a simple

```
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\large Abstract}
```

would work. Here you can modify `\large` to your liking. However, with [`abstract`](http://ctan.org/pkg/abstract), the preferred way is to modify `\abstractnamefont`:

```
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
```

for example.